# Unknown error message with code 400: LIMIT_INVALID' при загрузке файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

Использую питоновскую библиотеку Telethon.
Для загрузки медиа файла использую класс GetFileRequest.
 передаю параметры

```
input_file_location = InputFileLocation(volume_id=volume_id, 
    local_id=local_id, secret=secret)

file = telethon_client.invoke(GetFileRequest(
    location=input_file_location, offset=offset, limit=limit))
```

В параметре limit передаю размер файла в байтах (offset=0).
В результате возвращается ошибка:

> telethon.errors.RPCError: (RPCError(...), 'Unknown error message with code 400: LIMIT_INVALID')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Столкнулся с подобной проблемой. Ставь в качестве параметра limit для телеграм апи - число, делящееся на 1кб без остатка.
Например: 524288